# Reserving Space for Spark Application Master on Core Nodes in EMR

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

Can we reserve space for application master on core node so that task containers are restricted to run on core node in EMR. And I do not want disable it.

For us, task containers are consuming maximum memory in CORE nodes so most of the jobs are remaining in ACCEPTED mode as there is no memory to allocate for Spark AM.

I understand there is a parameter capacity-scheduler (yarn.scheduler.capacity.maximum-am-resource-percent) which defines maximum memory application master can get core nodes but could not find any parameter for minimum memory reserved for application masters to run.

I found [Qubole](https://docs.qubole.com/en/latest/admin-guide/cluster-admin/reserve-space-am.html) as such feature but we are not using Qubole.
How we can solve the issue ?